# HTML Tag Auto Complete in Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, html, notepad++

I would like for Notepad++ to add the closing tag when I finish typing the open tag. I know there is a plugin to do this for XML but it doesn't work on my HTML files and I have yet to find one that does.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try going into TextFX / TextFX Settings and check 'auto close XHTML tags'.  This makes it work in plain HTML files too. You may need to install it if using a newer version of Notepad++

1. Click Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager
2. On the "available" tab check the box by "TextFX Characters"
3. Click Install
4. Restart Notepad++
5. Enable the auto-close XHTM features as described above.

Comment: Also, the document language needs to be set to HTML, if it isn't already.

Comment: Thanks! Notepad++ is a great tool but looks like the authors are tough guys, such things should be on by default.

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ does this apply to?  Some of the newer versions don't seem to have TextFX anymore (such as the current release version, 5.9.8).

Comment: David do you know of a plugin which will auto-complete XHTML in php files?

Comment: @Anagio sorry, I do not. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: @DavidEbbo the auto-complete word setting built into Notepad++ does it