# Notepad++ - Highlight text and insert html <tag></tag> around it

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to have this feature in Notepad++:

1. select some text
2. insert an html ``` <tag>``</tag> ``` around it (ie. `<strong>`, `<em>` etc)

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with a predefined set of HTML tags or with a dialog box?

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, you can post an answer to your question and accept it. Others might benefit from it.

Comment: surround for Vim is what you actually want.

Comment: Maybe this related answer can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing

Comment: Maybe this related answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724634/notepad-shortcut-to-add-brackets-around-highlighted-text

Comment: Feature request for inserting tags (multi-line and single-line selection):
https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/feature-requests/180/

Answer (score 10):

I've found a plugin that does that, **Webedit** and it's available in Notepad++'s Plugin Manager (Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager).

Comment: Gone in v7.8.2.

Answer (score 4):

There's three ways to do this

---

Using the fingertext plugin

1. install "[FingerText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fingertext/files/Alpha%20Releases/FingerText%20-%200.5.60.zip/download)" plugin. (tested 0.5.60 version).
2. download [finger text snippet](https://bitbucket.org/netpie/fingertext-snippets/src%20).
3. select text, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.
4. for example type **b** (you can create your own "snippet `tag`" later).
   **Notes**: some version notepad++ must edit:
   `$[![]!]`  to  `$[![(key)SELECTION]!]`
5. press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

1. You can install any of this:

   - [emmet coding](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/downloads)
   - [zencoding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/)
2. select text, found and click menu "wrap with abbreviation".
3. type your `tag`
4. press `Ok`

---

Using multiple edit steps:

1. Preparation step

   - click "Setting" > "Preferences" menu.
   - click **Editing** tab.
   - check "Enable (Ctrl+Mouse click/selection)" in "Multi Editing Settings" groupbox
2. Execute this step

   1. Click before text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click after text, like this:

      ```
      ` click here  `   text    Ctrl+` click here `
      ```
   2. Typing whatever `<tag>`, will be around like this:

      `<tag>`text`<tag>`
   3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> twice, and type <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: You can and should consolidate all 3 posts into one answer, actually

Comment: please explain fingertext again, that's confusing me. Let say a simple text "abc" and i want to enclose it in <b>abc</b> how to add its snippet.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer . +1

Comment: How did you know about the SELECTION option? It's nowhere in the docs and this is the only reference I've found online about it. Are there others? Looking through the binary, I see SELECTIONORPASTE also.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724634/notepad-shortcut-to-add-brackets-around-highlighted-text

```
1) Mark text
2) Goto Macro -> start recording
3) Cut highlighted text (CTRL+C)
4) Type: "{" then do CTRL-V then Type "}"
5) goto Macro -> Stop Macro
6) Save Macro as a shortcut
```

Answer (score 0):

From a related [question](https://superuser.com/questions/131542/html-tag-auto-complete-in-notepad)

> Try going into TextFX / TextFX Settings and check 'auto close XHTML
>   tags'. This makes it work in plain HTML files too. You may need to
>   install it if using a newer version of Notepad++
>
> Click Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager On the
>   "available" tab check the box by "TextFX Characters" Click Install
>   Restart Notepad++ Enable the auto-close XHTM features as described
>   above.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Interesting, bit doesn't work for multi-line selection. So doesn't when you want to insert multiple <li> tags. Only the last <li> is closed with </li>.